ASP.NET Core MVC Application in Visual Studio 2022 Not Running with Secure SSL (HTTPS)
When I try to run my ASP.NET Core MVC application in visual studio 2022 with https the site runs as (Not secure) https://localhost:5138/ , saying Certification is not valid.
Try 1:

I tried running the visual studio 2022 as an administrator and ran the following commands in the order

dotnet dev-certs https --clean
Cleaning HTTPS development certificates from the machine. A prompt might get displayed to confirm the removal of some of the certificates.
HTTPS development certificates successfully removed from the machine.
dotnet dev-certs https --check
No valid certificate found.
dotnet dev-certs https
The HTTPS developer certificate was generated successfully.
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was not previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate.
There was an error trusting HTTPS developer certificate.
Try 2:
I tried to download the local host certificate by using the following powershell command
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "localhost" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.17={text}DNS=localhost&IPAddress=127.0.0.1&IPAddress=::1")
I ran the certificate manager Microsoft Manager Console (mmc) as an administrator
Clicked on File->Add Snap in -> Certificates
Copied the localhost certificate from Personal->Certificates to Trusted Root Certification Authority-> Certificates
I ran the IIS went on the default site and checked browse*:443(https) is running securely over the localhost.
But it was still not working for the ASP.NET Core MVC site which i tried to run from the visual studio 2022 with https
launchSettings.json code

{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:45941",
      "sslPort": 44322
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5138",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5138",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}


appsettings.json code
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Expectation: I am able to run the ASP.NET Core MVC application from visual studio with https with a secure connection on https://locahost:5138
Could you please let me know how i can resolve the issue. Let me know if there is a requirement to check any other configuration.
